# Is it possible to AirDrop a .html file to Safari?

Tags: ios, ios7, safari, airdrop

Is it possible to AirDrop a from my App generated .html file to another device. The device should open the .html file in Safari. Will this be possible if my app is not installed on both devices ?

I tried to AirDrop a .html file from Documents but I can't open it at the other device in Safari (only in some 3rd party apps). The .html file is unfortunately not accessible from internet.